# Creating a menu with while-loop and switch-statements

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a menu where you have four options:

- You can register a bird you have seen in a textfile.
- You can write the type of a bird you have seen.
- You can write the place where you have seen the bird.
- Close the program

This is what I have done so far:

```
import easyIO.*;

class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int counter = 0;
        while (counter != 4) {
            counter = meny();

            switch (counter) {
            case 1:
                ReigsterBird(1);
                break;
            case 2:
                WriteBirdType(2);
                break;
            case 3:
                WritePlace(3);
                break;
            case 4:
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Give a number between 1 and 4");

            }
        }
    }
```

But I keep getting these errors, and also i'm not sure how I can solve this. Is there something i'm missing?

```
Menu.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
counter = meny();
               ^
symbol:   method meny()
location: class Menu
loop.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
ReigsterBird(1);
^
symbol:   method ReigsterBird(int)
location: class Menu
Menu.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
WriteBirdType(2);
^
symbol:   method WriteBirdType(int)
location: class Menu
loop.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
WritePlace(3);
^
symbol:   method WritePlace(int)
location: class Menu
4 errors
```

I would appreciate if someone could help out on this so I could create a menu where you have four options you can choose from.

Comment: Well the error messages are quite clear.  You are calling methods that don't exist.  You need to write them.

Comment: @Brandon hmm. is there any hint or example you could give on how I can create a method from those statements? would appreciate it

Comment: See Zong's answer below.  He shows you how to define the methods.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the methods. I know it's confusing as a beginner, so here's what it should look like:

```
import easyIO.*;

class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }

    public static int meny() {
        ...
    }

    public static void ReigsterBird(int x) {
        ...
    }
}
```